# Give user the permission to add new items in the listview from basic screen

Tags: android, listview

So i have created an app that at its basicsceen when it starts contains 2 buttons, Play and instuctions. When u press play it shows a listview that contains an amount of stories. I used a  custom adapter to have my own style on the listview.

Now i would like to have a new button at the basic screen along with play,istuctions and when u press it, it will pop a new actvity with 3 fields that the user will have to fill. Those will be the title of the story,the content and the difficulty level that he wants to add.

So the basic question is. Is it possible to add a new story to the list with the data that user gave me?
I have searched the internet but couldnt fine something usefull(from what i am reading what i am trying to do is not possible and a bad practice)...

Thanks a lot in advance and i apologize for any mistakes i have made (still new to android and to StackOverflow). Thanks again.

Here is the current code of my classes.

StoriesListed.java class

```
public class StoriesListed_Activity extends Activity {



private ArrayList<Story> myStories=new ArrayList<Story>();


private void populateStoryList() {           

    StoriesLab stories=new StoriesLab();
    stories.setMyStories();



    myStories=stories.updateMyStories();



}

private void populateListView(){
    final ArrayAdapter<Story> myadapter=new MylistAdapter();
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_layout);
    list.setAdapter(myadapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int         position, long id) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(StoriesListed_Activity.this,      Storyone.class);

                intent.putExtra("key", myStories);
                intent.putExtra("secondkey",position);

                startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.storiesview_layout);



    populateStoryList();

    populateListView();


}

private class MylistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Story>{
        public MylistAdapter(){
            super(StoriesListed_Activity.this,R.layout.storiesview_layout,myStories);
        }


    @Override
    public  View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v=convertView;



        if(v==null){

            v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customizedstoriesview,parent,false);

            CheckBox checkbox_holder=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        }



        //find the story to work with

        Story currentstory = myStories.get(position);

        //fill the view

        Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"horror.ttf");
        TextView mytextview=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TitleView) ;
        mytextview.setTypeface(typeface);



        TextView Titletext=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TitleView);     //SETTING THE TEXT OF THE TITLE
        Titletext.setText(currentstory.getName());

        RatingBar myratingbar=(RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar); //setting the Stars ratio for the difficulty
        myratingbar.setRating(currentstory.getRatingbar());

        return v;
    }
}
```

}

Story class

```
public class Story implements Serializable {
private String name;
private String storycontent;
private int ratingbarratio;


public Story(String name,int ratingbarratio,String storycontent){
    super();
    this.name=name;
    this.storycontent=storycontent;
    this.ratingbarratio=ratingbarratio;

}

public String getName(){
return name;
}

public int getRatingbar(){
    return ratingbarratio;
}
public String getStorycontent(){
    return storycontent;
}

}
```

where i store the displayed stories. Mt storieslab class

```
public class StoriesLab{
private ArrayList<Story> myStories;


public StoriesLab(){
    myStories=new ArrayList<Story>();


}

public void setMyStories() {
    myStories.add(new Story("aaaaaaaaaaa"));
    myStories.add(new Story("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"));
    myStories.add(new Story("Sherlock Holmes is not the only one",3,"cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"));
    myStories.add(new Story("o xsulinos stratioths",1,"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"));
    myStories.add(new Story("random name",3,""));
    myStories.add(new Story("random name",2,""));
    myStories.add(new Story("random name",3,""));
    myStories.add(new Story("random name",1,""));
    myStories.add(new Story("random name",3,""));
    myStories.add(new Story("random name",2,""));
    myStories.add(new Story("random name",3,""));
    myStories.add(new Story("random name",1,""));



}

 public void addnewstory(Story object){
 myStories.add(object);
}

public ArrayList<Story> updateMyStories(){
    return myStories;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is to manage a data set. In other words, your stories would sit in some sort of database, or data bank and then when it is modified, you could trigger a refresh of your list view.

There are a ton of ways to do this (local databases, flat files, etc.). For what you are doing, it sounds like flat files would work fine. I am currently doing this in my app by storing JSON objects as text but you can do it any way that suits your needs.

Check out https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Hope this helps.